# Spawn Player ENOENT error while emulate genymotion

Tags: genymotion, nativescript

I'm not sure this is NativeScript or GenyMotion error.

`tns emulate android --geny "devices name"` and I got this error `Spawn player ENOENT`.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple reasons you can this error.

1. First make sure you have https://www.genymotion.com/ Installed, if you don't have it installed then the --geny won't work and fail.
2. Make sure that you can start that specific VM from inside GenyMotion.
3. On Windows, you need to make sure that

   > C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion

is in your path.  (Assuming you installed GenyMotion to the default path.)   On Linux & MacOS I believe it will already be in your path.

One way to verify if GenyMotion is in your path on any of the Operating systems is to type:

> genyshell

At a command prompt/shell; if it loads then you can type "quit" to exit.  But this will verify that all the GenyMotion support files can be ran from anywhere on your command line.

Comment: Works !
number 3, set the path

Comment: I figured it was the path; but the other two are to make sure it is installed and working first.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this same problem. I'm using NativeScript on a Mac and in my case the custom Genymotion version of ADB was causing the problem.

To resolve, open Genymotion go to `Settings > ADB > Use custom Android SDK tools`

In the `Android SDK` textbox, provide the path to your Android SDK directory. If you're not sure where your directory is, run this in your terminal to get the path:

`$ echo $ANDROID_HOME`

Copy that path in to the Genymotion settings and try to emulate your app again. This should fix the ADB conflicts and allow NativeScript to emulate your app properly. Hope this helps.